# does anybody checked subscriptions behaviour on milo server working in kubernetes environment?

Tags: milo

I’m trying to run Milo server, the same as in the server example, but in the Kubernetes cluster installed on Raspberry Pis. And mostly it works fine. I can read/write Variable nodes. But I couldn’t make subscriptions working. When I run server on local machine all works fine, but the same code doesn’t work on the pod. I can create subscription, in server logs I’m seeing that Milo tries to publish data, but client doesn’t received any notification/events. I checked several clients, no success. May be someone already faced that problem? Any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated.

I have mosquito working in the same manner and pano client library receives all subscriptions well. May be I’m wrong but it looks like tcp stack works well in that case.